# What kind of Android notification is this?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have a Service that has to run all the time, so after a long research I think that only way to have it running is use a Foreground Service, and for to use it, I need a notification. The problem starts when I have to set it, that it's always appearing the icon of the notification in the top of the screen and this is very disturbing. There's no problem if the notifications apears when you open the Notification Bar. I have an example of this case:
If you look to the image 1, I have the Facebook's Messenger popup window opened, but no notification there of the app. Ok, but If you see in the image 2 when I expand the bar, there's the notification. What kind of notification is this?

Image1 => https://db.tt/t7fLfGQP
Image2 => https://db.tt/ougBIOiF

Also I tried to set the `Notification.PRIORITY_MIN` and `.SetOngoing(true)` but I can't get the desired functionality. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)` is the right way to achieve this. Please post more of your code - you're probably doing something wrong:) The other reason: maybe you are testing it on device lower than API 16? (Priorities were introduced in API 16).

Comment: Thanks for reply @MaciejCiemięga! Finally I got it working on up to API 16 changing the constructor. But what about api 15? Should I set `.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;` instead setting minim priority?

Comment: No, you cannot achieve this result on API lower than 16. It's just not possible - the icon will always be visible in statusbar. BTW it's better to use `Notification.Builder` (or `NotificationCompat.Builder`) to build a notification and do not set values on `Notification` directly. `Builder` will take care of compatibility across API levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using `setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)` but here you also add `.SetOngoing(true)` so  Ongoing notifications cannot be manually removed from the notification drawer. so you have to remove this property and Try also get more Detail from here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Thats it...

Comment: Yes, that's it. It's needed to set the two params at once! Thank you for reply @Jay